# How can I hide node content from taxonomy term page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

How can I hide node content from the taxonomy term page. That was the related content (Term reference node)  of that particular taxonomy term.

I am trying to hide it using hook_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables), but I'm unable to resolve the issue. Please suggest the best solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on drupal 9 today there is a default view called **Taxonomy term**(*taxonomy_term*) for displaying content related to taxonomy term on `/taxonomy/term/%` if you want to override display of all the vocabularies you can simply go to views (`/admin/structure/views/`) and disable the  **Taxonomy term** view and then you can change the display settings of a vocabulary in the `Manage Display` section. It is not completely though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Drupal 7 module that does this: [Disable Term Node Listings](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_term_node_listings)

Having looked at it's code, not sure it's possible to translate it to D8.

There's a more active question here - one of the answers suggests using `MY_THEME_preprocess_page`:

[Drupal - Disable listing of nodes on taxonomy term page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498639/drupal-disable-listing-of-nodes-on-taxonomy-term-page)